# display model contents dynamically in View MVC4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a homepage that will display a table with some data for each user. The back-end handles that and I have a list in my model. I am trying to view a dynamic table based on this list and be able to delete elements from without having to hit refresh. I do not know where to start to do something like this. Any help?

Here is what I have so far:
Inside HomePage controller I have an action returning Json representation of the model. Have of 'HpModel' gets set in the login controller and the other is in this one:

```
public JsonResult GetUserInfo(HomePageModel HpModel)
    {
        DBOps ops = new DBOps();
        HpModel.PhoneDisplay = ops.getDisplayInfo(HpModel.ExtNum);
        HpModel.NumberOfLines = HpModel.PhoneDisplay.Count;
        return Json(HpModel);
    }
```

In my view I have a javascript to grab this model:

```
 function getInfo() {
            alert('here');
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUserInfo", "HomePage")',
                data: json,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

I am not sure what is going wrong, and not 100% sure its the way to be done anyway. 
Help is appreciated :)

Comment: Create actions like `GetTableData` and `DeleteRow(recordId)` in your controller. Encapsulate your list with a model and use built-in `JsonResult` to complete actions. Call actions with ajax on your client code. You can keep your records' properties in your table rows via data- attribute.

Comment: thanks that's a palce to start with. What I need at the end is to be able to delete as much as the user wants from the table and once they hit submit changes will be pushed to the database. is this something doable with the approach you described ? Would these actions be in my "Homepag" controller?

Comment: Sure. You can hold the actions in cache/session, like a series of transactions. For simplicity, create a session variable to hold those actions for that user. When user call the DeleteRow action, push this request to session variable. Implement another controller action, say `CommitRows` with a functionality that checks session variable and actually executes/commits requests.

Comment: So would my action be of type JsonResult, and the data be passed by as JSON files? is that what you meant in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

One more idea. You may use jQuery to hide  and callback function to $Post to your Delete ActionResult.

For examp: (here I created easy example without $post: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gubal/eACN7/))

```
<script>
    $('.delete').click(function()
    {
     $(this).closest('tr').hide(callback);
        function callback() {
            $post(/Home/Delete/....
          });

  </script>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Marry</td>
        <td>10 points</td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>8 points</td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lara</td>
        <td>5 points</td>
        <td><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```